# How to prevent the application install from play store without user permission?

Tags: android, security, store, playback, package-managers

How to prevent the application install from play store without user permission? Is there any Android SO protection to avoid this behavior?

Comment: It's not possibile to install PlayStore's Apps without User permission. Maybe you're referring about their UPDATES. You can disable Auto-Updates from PlayStore App's specific page and un-check "auto-updates" checkbox.

Comment: In this case, I don't think you will get success. Just think if you could do that, you would block the competitor app installation. 'O'